# SQL Server with French_CI_AS Collation date conversion

Tags: sql-server-2016, datetime, collation, type-conversion, localization

I have a French installation of SQL Server using `French_CI_AS` Collation. For legacy reasons, a table column stores data as `VARCHAR` which is later converted to the right type, akin to variant in C++.

Two rows in this column have data as:

```
2020-10-12 22:54:40

2020-10-13 04:42:10
```

The second date fails when converting to `DATETIME` with default options. The application uses ODBC escape sequences. SQL such as `COLMVALUE >= {ts'2020-01-01 00:00:00'}` fails with the error:

> La conversion d'un type de données nvarchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites

I did a `DBCC useroptions`  and the server has date format set to `dmy`. Why is the 2nd row failing? It looks like it is trying to interpret "13" as the month. If the format is `dmy`, shouldn't both dates fail?

Also, it is interesting to note that on this server, the following fails:

```sql
DECLARE @datevar DATETIME = '2020-10-13 04:42:10';    
SELECT @datevar;
```

But this works:

```sql
DECLARE @datevar DATETIME2 = '2020-10-13 04:42:10';    
SELECT @datevar;
```

I am aware that `DATETIME2` is more accurate and has greater range than `DATETIME`. However, it seems that even the parsing is different for the two here.

Comment: I'd recommend to read few articles by Aaron Bertrand about handling dates in SQL Server. He uses French language examples a lot there. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/ https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9315/recommended-sql-server-date-formats/ https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. That was a useful link.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a collation issue. This is a language / locale / culture issue. Your DB (or your login's default language) is set to "French" (most likely) and they use Day then Month formats, not Month then Day, hence your statement is attempting to use month 13.

Try this to reproduce:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE French;
DECLARE @datevar DATETIME = '2020-10-13 04:42:10';
/*
Le paramètre de langue est passé à Français.
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line XXXXX
La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a
    créé une valeur hors limites.
*/

GO
PRINT '-----';
GO

SET LANGUAGE English;
DECLARE @datevar DATETIME = '2020-10-13 04:42:10';
GO
```

You have two options for changing this:

1. [SET LANGUAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql)
   This controls not just the date format but also currency symbol, day and month names, etc. This might not be the best choice given that it controls more than just the date format, but it *might* be easier if it only requires updating the login's default language instead of updating a lot of code to do option # 2.
2. [SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql)
   This controls just the date format:

   ```sql
   SET LANGUAGE French;
   DECLARE @datevar DATETIME = '2020-10-13 04:42:10';
   /*
   Le paramètre de langue est passé à Français.
   Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line XXXXX
   La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a
       créé une valeur hors limites.
   */

   SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
   DECLARE @datevar2 DATETIME = '2020-10-13 04:42:10';

   SELECT @datevar AS [@datevar], @datevar2 AS [@datevar2];
   /*
   @datevar    @datevar2
   NULL        2020-10-13 04:42:10.000
   */
   ```

Regarding your other questions:

> If the format is `dmy`, shouldn't both dates fail?

and

> (implied) Why do `DATETIME` and `DATETIME2` appear to parse the same date differently?

All of that is because working with dates is really messy. The documentation for `DATEFORMAT` states not only that:

> **datetime** and **smalldatetime** interpretations may not match **date**, **datetime2**, or **datetimeoffset**

but also:

> Some character string formats, for example ISO 8601, are interpreted independently of the DATEFORMAT setting.

While the documentation doesn't tie those two statements together, testing does show that [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted dates (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD) are "interpreted independently of the DATEFORMAT setting" only for `DATE`, `DATETIME2`, and `DATETIMEOFFSET`. That is why the date of `'2020-10-13'` respects the value of `DATEFORMAT` for your `DATETIME` variable (and hence receives an error for cultures where the day comes before the month, whether separating date parts with "-" or "/"), but is parsed correctly for your `DATETIME2` test (and always will regardless of the current culture or value of `DATEFORMAT`).

P.S. I would not consider a variant / `SQL_VARIANT` / `object`, etc to be the "right" type ;-)

Comment: Thanks Solomon. The key here is this: SET LANGUAGE français;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '02/09/2017');
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2017-02-09');
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2017-02-09 01:23:45.678'); Its not just the date but the lang setting too. And yes, I didnt mean variant is the right type. That just came over the top of my head thinking of lectures that may come in, why are you storing date as string :-)